# What exactly is the procedure that the TeX line-breaking algorithm uses when it needs to set overfull boxes?

Tags: line-breaking

The TeXbook describes (in chapter 14) in detail how TeX calculates the total demerits associated with breaking a paragraph into lines and that TeX chooses the sequence of breakpoints that yield the fewest total demerits (in a process with three passes). However, it only briefly describes what exactly happens if no sequence of breakpoints exists that satisfies the requirements:

> Roughly speaking, \TeX\ breaks paragraphs into lines in the following
> way: Breakpoints are inserted between words or after hyphens so as to
> produce lines whose badnesses do not exceed the current ^|\tolerance|.
> If there's no way to insert such breakpoints, an ^{overfull box} is
> set.

No further details on the overfull box scenario follow. I am interested in these details: Can one describe in simple terms which words TeX chooses to stick out into the margin in such a case? (Or do you have to read the TeX source code to understand that?) Since TeX considers a paragraph as a whole, the issue of not having a permissible sequence of breakpoints is not really caused by a single word.

Furthermore, I think that the above statement from the TeXbook is not entirely correct: When a paragraph contains a `\linebreak`, it may be set with underfull lines instead. This scenario basically satisfies the premise "there's no way to insert such breakpoints", yet TeX sets underfull lines instead of overfull lines as stated above.

(This question is mainly out of interest. But there is indeed a scenario where a paragraph with overfull lines may end up in a finished document, namely if the excess size of the overfull lines is not more than `\hfuzz`.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, `\penalty-10000` adds a *penalty*, but `\tolerance` sets a limit for the *badness* which the lines of the paragraph must not exceed. When you e. g. place a `\linebreak` early in the first line of a paragraph, the spaces in the first line need to be stretched a lot, so this line gets a high badness exceeding `\tolerance`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX chooses line breaks based on a calculation of line demerits that
are totaled in an amount called *total demerits*.

A first pass that doesn't apply the hyphenation capability of TeX might fail to obey the limits that are set by an integer parameter `\pretolerance`. But the second pass of TeX always succeed. It might not be successful in the sense that TeX has to create overfull lines. Underfull lines are only created if the user wants them.

What I mean. You can set `\parfillskip=0pt` and give TeX a short line with, say, just one space and TeX reports and underfull line. The author is always responsible for the last line break; nothing is inserted by TeX in a one-line paragraph. Similar, a line break command that outputs `\penalty-10000`
forces TeX to obey the wish of the author to break the line at this point. It's a forced break nothing that TeX inserts.

Here is how TeX operates; I try to use simple words but it is a technical topic:
TeX breaks lines at glue (including at kern followed by glue and at
the end of inline math followed by glue) or at a penalty, i.e., a
hyphen in the text, a hyphen inserted by TeX in the second pass, after a relation in math mode, etc. as well as a `\penalty-10000` as explained above.

Of course, TeX counts the beginning of the text as the initial
breakpoint. To create a paragraph TeX goes from a place where a break is possible---in the second pass the place might be created by TeX through an inserted hyphen---to the next until the width of the collected material including either shrink- or stretchability allows TeX to build a line with a badness obeying the current tolerance together with one of the earlier found (or forced) breakpoints. TeX marks such a place as a breakpoint and remembers for it the associated previous breakpoint so that it can later go from the end of the paragraph back to the start with the lines that minimize the total demerits.

TeX also creates a breakpoint if it sees a user inserted `\penalty-10000`. Then it starts the process as if it were at the start of the paragraph. No following breakpoint can reach over this breakpoint, i.e., the next breakpoint must record this user forced breakpoint as the previous breakpoint.

If no place can be found to build a line with a badness at most as large as the current tolerance
TeX stops the processing if it is in the first pass and then it
starts the second pass. Otherwise if TeX is in the second pass it
looks for the next place where a break is possible without building an underfull line. This becomes a breakpoint although the line is overfull. Next, TeX continues the process.
Thus the second pass goes through the whole paragraph. Note, a
paragraph can have more than one overfull line.

If `\emergencystretch` isn't 0pt and the second pass couldn't do what was requested, i.e., find breakpoints without an overfull line or reduce the number of lines if `\looseness=-1`, then TeX
starts a third pass that works like the second. The difference is that TeX adds the dimension of the `\emergencystretch` to the stretchability of every line. Thus, TeX accepts a place as a breakpoint although the width of the collected material and the stretchability in the material cannot
fill the line with a badness less or equal to the current
tolerance. But the width plus the stretchability plus the dimension
`\emergencystretch` is large enough to do that; visually such a line is underfull.

There are several parameters that influence the reporting and the
marking. As you said the `\hfuzz` dimen can omit the overfull rule but
it doesn't change the fact: there is an overfull line. Another
parameter called `\hbadness` is responsible if a warning is issued.

Thus, I don't see why the cited text of the TeXbook is wrong as it
is a high level informal description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It may be a bit hair-splitting, but the reason I think the cited statement is not entirely correct is this: The cited statement has a premise ("If there is no way to insert breakpoints such that no line has a badness exceeding `\tolerance`...") and a conclusion ("... an overfull box is set.") and the text states that whenever the premise is satisfied, the conclusion holds (because the conclusion is not "... an overfull box *may be* set.", but "... an overfull box *is* set."). [Continued in next comment]

Comment: [continuation] But when you e. g. have a multi-line paragraph and place a `\linebreak` early in the first line of the paragraph, the premise is satistied: There is no way to insert breakpoints such that the first line has a badness not exceeding `\tolerance`. Yet the output does not contain an overfull line (but an underfull line instead). So the conclusion does not hold despite the fact that the premise is satisfied.

Comment: I see your point but one can also read the word "produces" in a way
that only those lines are meant that receive their breakpoint by TeX.
Moreover the text starts with "Roughly speaking" and the next
paragraph of the TeXbook has this as its first sentence: "But the
informal description of line breaking in the previous paragraph is an
oversimplification of what really happens." I thought your question
asks for an explanation that stays on the informal level but has more
details.

Comment: I am very sorry if you did unnecessary work on your answer because my question was not clear enough. Perhaps I should have emphasized that I understand the basic workings of the line breaking algorithm and was interested in the details of the overfull box scenario. I have edited the question a bit to avoid misunderstandings for future readers.

Comment: In addition to what you wrote about the context of the cited text ("Roughly speaking ...", "... But the informal description of line breaking in the previous paragraph is an oversimplification of what really happens."), I just remembered what Knuth wrote in the preface: "Another noteworthy characteristic of this manual is that it doesn't
always tell the ^{truth}. When certain concepts of \TeX\ are introduced
informally, general rules will be stated; afterwards you will find that the
rules aren't strictly true." So one should indeed not take the cited text too seriously.